need help in CVzone
Here is the code I tried to run
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    img = cap.read()
    cv2.putText(img, "C", (100, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 5, (0, 255, 0), 5)
    cv2.imshow("PutText", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

And this output my laptop executed
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\IT\CV_project\PutText.py", line 8, in <module>
    cv2.putText(img, "C", (100, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 5, (0, 255, 0), 5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.9.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'putText'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - img is not a numerical tuple
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
"

The result I waited was the text written on my camera image.

The correct way is ret, img = cap.read()

I tried this which worked well.
The main difference is this line which Read a frame from the video capture in the while loop:

ret, frame = cap.read()

Here is the code:
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
text = "This is some text on the video!"

# Font style and parameters (adjust these as needed)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
font_scale = 1
font_color = (255, 255, 255)  # White color
thickness = 2
text_position = (50, 50)  # Adjust for text placement

# Process each frame of the video
while True:
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  
  if not ret:
    break

  # Put the text on the frame
  cv2.putText(frame, text, text_position, font, font_scale, font_color, thickness)

  # Display the frame with text
  cv2.imshow("Video with Text", frame)

  # Exit on 'q' press
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

# Release resources
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

And i get a video image with text on it.
